# AJAX JSON How to detect a Boolean value and create conditions?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend

My webpage is receiving through AJAX GET requests Arrays with strings, and a Boolean.

The objects within the array are displayed subsequently to shape a chat app, the received array represents messages to display in a chatbox.   However, some of the messages have media in them.

Therefore, to recognize such message with image source in them, I added a Boolean Value (media=True : There is an image source).

With my current code, all arrays are testing their source in an empty `<img src"">` which creates a real mess on the chat box with unknown images. I need to be able to generate with JS an HTML image when an Object has a media = True with a source of 'mediasrc'.

[AJAX Array in details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsuop.png)

HTML:

```
<div id="display"></div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "/checkview",
            success: function go(response) {
                console.log(response);
                $("#display").empty();
                for (var model of response.models_to_return) {
                    var temp = "<div class='container darker'><b>" +
                        model.user_id + "</b><p>" +
                        model.room + "</p><span class='time-left'>" +
                        model.datetime + "</span><img src=../static/" +
                        model.mediasrc + ".png></div>";
                    $("#display").append(temp);
                }
            },
            error: function(response) {
                //alert('An error occured')
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
})
</script>
```

By the way, this code works fine, but it's literally brute forcing all messages trying to fill an img:

[image]

Comment: Please replace your ajax call with sample data here, and put that and your HTML in a snippet demo using the editor. I would help, but you posted your data as an image. We don't debug images here. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure I understand the question, but you could create a utility function that takes the model and returns either the `<img>` markup or an empty string depending on whether `model.mediasrc` is present (or whatever condition is appropriate for your needs).

This probably isn't the exact implementation you need, but it demonstrates the pattern:

```js
function imgMarkup (model) {
  if (model.mediasrc) {
    return `<img src="${model.mediasrc}" />`     
  }
  return '';
}
```

```js
for (var model of response.models_to_return) {
  const temp=`
    <div class='container darker'>
      <b>${model.user_id}</b>
      <p>${model.room}</p>
      <span class='time-left'>${model.datetime}</span>
      ${imgMarkup(model)}
    </div>`;
    $("#display").append(temp);
}
```

Comment: Ty for your answer, yes you understood pretty well the question. However, I don't know how to integrate such function in my temp variable.

Comment: May I integrate into the var temp your function imgMarkup ?

Comment: It's already in my example. Declare the `imgMarkup` function above your `setInterval` call.

Answer (score 0):

while this is something that front-end frameworks handle particularly well, a common convention would be to split your template HTML. For example:

```
for (var model of response.models_to_return) {
    var temp = "<div class='container darker'>"
    + "<b>" + model.user_id + "</b>"
    + "<p>" + model.room + "</p>"
    + "<span class='time-left'>" + model.datetime + "</span>";
    if (model.media) {
        //add img to template, could also check model.mediasrc != null
        temp += "<img src=../static/" + model.mediasrc + ".png>"
    }
    temp += "</div>";

    $("#display").append(temp);
}
```

If you want to write code up to the latest conventions, replace double quotes with back ticks, and reference variables with ${var_name}.

For example:

```
+ "<b>" + model.user_id + "</b>"
```

becomes:

```
+ `<b>${model.user_id}</b>`
```